# How to deploy Azure RM template without providing variables that have default values defined?

Tags: azure

I would like to deploy a template from the [Azure Resource Manager QuickStart Templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates).

Many of the templates there have a default value specified in the template file (for example this one [azuredeploy.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vm-domain-join/azuredeploy.json)
):

```
"ouPath": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": "",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Specifies an organizational unit (OU) for the domain account. Enter the full distinguished name of the OU in quotation marks. Example: 'OU=testOU; DC=domain; DC=Domain; DC=com"
  }
},
```

However, the corresponding [azuredeploy.parameters.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vm-domain-join/azuredeploy.parameters.json) does not define the `ouPath` value.

When I specify the file in `--parameters-file` in the Azure CLI call:

```
azure group deployment create "${resource_group_name}" "${deployment_name}" --template-uri "${template_uri}" --parameters-file ${parameters_file}
```

I get an error:

> info:    Executing command group deployment create
>        error:    Template and Deployment "parameters" objects lengths do not match
>                Deployment Parameter file does not have { ouPath } defined.
>         error:   Error information has been recorded to /Users/techraf/.azure/azure.err
>         error:   group deployment create command failed

If I define add the value explicitly to the `parameters.json` file, the deployment works properly.

---

**Main question:**

The sheer number of examples (`parameters.json`) in the above Azure repository without explicitly specified values makes me think, there must be a way to tell Azure to use default value instead of providing it in `parameters.json`.

Is there a way to avoid adding the values that have `defaultValue` defined in the template file when using Azure CLI?

---

**Additional question:**

Worse yet, in the example I have given above, the default value is empty and if I specify an empty value in the `parameters.json`:

```
"ouPath": {
  "value": ""
},
```

I get an interactive prompt for the value.

How can I avoid that?

Comment: Using a default value should just be a case of not supplying it in the parameters file, I do this all the time and it works fine. I wonder if the issue here is that the default value is an empty string, if you set the default to something else does it then work?

Comment: In my case, it doesn't work for any value, for example [201-vm-winrm-windows](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-winrm-windows) requires me to define `windowsOSVersion` in `parameters.json` even though it has a default value of `2012-R2-Datacenter` in the template.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of PowerShell cmdlets and Azure SDK? I had issues in the past where random paramters would complain about a lack of value (whilst others with default values would be fine), this has gone away in the last few months

Comment: I'm not using PowerShell, I am using Azure CLI. 0.10.5 on OS X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was a bug in Azure CLI 0.10.5.

The problem does not happen with the 0.10.6 although the [release notes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/releases/tag/v0.10.6-October2016) do not mention this fix explicitly.